# How to use regex to match word with apostrophe

Tags: python

I have two files: text_data and word_list. I am trying to write a function that removes all the words that appear in word_list from text_data. However, I think I did not write my regex correctly. Here is my code

```
def remove_stopwords_from_file(text_data, word_list):
file_content = text_data
for word in word_list.split():
    file_content = re.sub(r"\b"+word+r"\b"," ", file_content)
return file_content
```

Here is part of output

```
opening monologue jerry 'm line supermarket two women   front  one  total   eight dollars three dollars course choose pay use pause   gesture   audience   response audience cheque jerry cheque now fact 's a woman   front      's writing
```

Some words are replaced by blanks. But for words with apostrophe, only half of the word is replaced. For example, "I'm" is supposed replaced by a blank, but only "I" is replaced and "'m" is still there.

I am new to python, hope someone could help me solve this problem. Thanks

Sample of word_list

```
below
between
both
but
by
can't
cannot
could
couldn't
```

Sample of text_data

```
% Opening monologue

Jerry: So, I'm on line at the supermarket. Two women in front of me. One of

them, her total was eight dollars, the other three dollars. They both

of course choose to pay by the use of the (pause and gesture to audience
```

Comment: Please include `text_data` as well as `word_list`. Thanks.

Comment: Is the word "I" in your stop list? And if so, does it appear before "I'm"?

Comment: "I" is not in the stop list, only "I'm" is.

Comment: @user8853925: Well, your regex correctly handles words with apostrophes, so the issue must be something else

Answer (score 1):

This would be a question better suited for [regex](/questions/tagged/regex). What's likely happening is "I" is in `word_list`, and since `'` is considered a word boundary, `\bI\b` matches the "I" in "I'm". A simple fix would be to place "I'm" before "I" in the `word_list`. A more complete fix would be to create a new regex where apostrophes aren't included in the word boundaries. This can be done in a roundabout fashion by replacing all apostraphes with another unicode character.

Comment: In my case, "I" is not in the stop list, only "I'm" is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried something similar. Just tell me if it makes sense.

File a.txt
`with open('a.txt', 'r') as content_file:`
    `content = content_file.read()`

`print content`
"d sgr sdfxc fbcxvhstdf bc gerdfx'g srdf sdg'ffg d's gfd'g fd\n"

`re.sub(r'gerdfx\'g'," ",content)`
"d sgr sdfxc fbcxvhstdf bc    srdf sdg'ffg d's gfd'g fd\n"
It did substitute with spaces.

Then I tried to do the same with a variable.
`x = "gerdfx'g"`
`re.sub(r''+x," ",content)`
"d sgr sdfxc fbcxvhstdf bc    srdf sdg'ffg d's gfd'g fd\n"

This also seemed to work. Can you look at this and say what you tried differently?